# Auto Resizing Different Row Divs

Tags: css, html, height

Alright, I have two rows of the same class divs on different pages. On page 1, there is one row with a fair amount of text, and the size settings for it works perfectly. On page 2, there is much less text in the div "box", but the size is too large.

What I want to accomplish is for the 3 divs on page 1 to have the correct current height settings, but I want the divs on page 2 to have a shorter height setting. The only issue with this is that this must be accomplished all within one Css class (parent & siblings).

here is a picture for an example:

[image]

2a: This is the current height settings, and it works perfectly with the larger amount of text.

2b: The shorter text's box is too long, needs to be shortened but still be in the same class as 2a's.

2c & 2d: The correct auto adjusted heights

```
.box{
    height: 400px;
}

.box .box_content{
    height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Can you not just remove the height from the css and the div will automatically size according to its content?

Comment: I need the divs to be equal: so that the bottoms and tops of the divs are equally aligned horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the height setting on .box the heights will dynamically fill with the content.

If each row needs to be equal height you could use jquery to find the tallest div in the row and set the others accordingly.

Comment: That could work probably, anyway to do it with CSS first though?

Comment: is it possible to have different content heights within the rows?

Comment: No, they need to be equal, just adjusted so that each row is smaller/larger based on the content inside of it.

Comment: no my question is can each column within the row have a different content height?  I understand the rows need to be equal.

Comment: with the same CSS classes all the way around you'll need a javascript solution to solve this

Comment: Sorry, the row height doesn't matter. I meant the actual 3 divs in a row would need to be the same height. I'll look into a jquery fix for this since it is wordpress based and far easier to adapt it I guess...